# how to delete (Reset) AppState data in Google play games

Tags: android, google-play-services

My current android application stores data "in The Cloud" using AppStateManager.

I store the data as a json string. I now need to add more data to this json structure and wanted to "Start from scratch" so wanted to delete the appstate data already persisted. I have tried

```
AppStateManager.delete(googleClient, Key)
```

and also

```
AppStateManager.update(googlClient, key, null)
```

neither worked as `stateListResult.getStateBuffer().getCount()` still shows a count of 1

how do you completely remove AppStateManager data from the cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is a way to do that programatically. The only way to remove the data is for the user to reset it by disconnecting the app from G+.

That said, Google is now recommending the use of [Saved Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames) (`Snapshot`) instead of Cloud Save (`AppState`) for cloud storage.

Removing existing data with Saved Games (`Snapshot`) is very simple, so you may want to look into using it for cloud storage instead.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to assist me. Saved Games looks like it fits the bill. Cheers.

Comment: Glad to help. Saved Games is IMHO an big improvement for cloud storage - and it is not too difficult to implement. Good luck!